Comparing one value to mean or median of a group
I have very limited statistical knowledge or experience, so I am looking for some guidance on my approach for statistical analysis.
I have a group of 60 values. I am looking to compare the last value within the group to summary level statistics of the 60 values. I know that when comparing two groups, comparison of means and SD can be performed. However, I am not sure how, or if, one value can be compared to an aggregated group. Essentially, I am wanting to know how much the one value varies from the median or mean of the 60 values, and the statistical significance of the variance.
Thank you.

It sounds like you might be looking for a prediction interval.  Could you please explain what you mean by "significance of the variance"?

Hi @whuber, thanks for your response. Interesting, I am not familiar with prediction intervals but it sounds like this could be on track for what I am looking for. In terms of "signficance of the variance", I mean that I would like to compare the single value to the dispersion of the group of values

You could evaluate which quantile of the original data your new point falls at, i.e., whether it is larger than (say) 90% of the original data. Put differently, you would set up the empirical cumulative distribution function of the original data and evaluate it at the new data point. We might be able to help you more if you could give a few more details.
